# Given a color, how do I find which color it's closest to?

Tags: colors

Let's say that I have a list of valid color values like [0x67FF82, 0x808080, 0xffffff, ...] and given an input color, in hex, I want to find which color in the list of acceptable colors that the input color is closest to.

My thought is that I'd find the color in which the absolute value of the difference of the red, green, and blue values is smallest.  Is this correct?

Comment: Numerically, I think that would work, but due to the non-linear curve of how human's eyes see the intensity of color, I do think that it may not always choose the "correct" color that a human may pick. Just a thought :)

Comment: +1, that's it, but for more precise/more ergonomic use, you should always consider using a proper nonlinear function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to quantify the "distance" between colors - in math, they'd call it a metric. Many people are intuitively pretty comfortable with the [Euclidean metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) for example - it's simply the distance between two points as measured with a ruler. In the case of colors, things are more complicated because of subjective perception of different colors.

There's a [pretty mathy wikipedia article about color difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference), which includes links to different implementations.

> The difference or distance between two colors is a metric of interest in color science. It allows people to quantify a notion that would otherwise be described with adjectives, to the detriment of anyone whose work is color critical. Common definitions make use of the Euclidean distance in a device independent color space.

In particular, there's [Python Colormath](http://code.google.com/p/python-colormath/), an implementation in python that converts between different color encodings and also seems to have a function for calculating the distance between two colors. If you happen to be coding in python, that sounds helpful, although I unfortunately don't have any personal experience with that tool. There's also similar resources available for [MATLAB and Excel provided by the authors of CIE2000](http://www.ece.rochester.edu/~gsharma/ciede2000/), a leading color-difference formula.

Comment: Thanks!  I am coding in Python so that's convenient!